# Strange artifacts in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm getting extremely strange results in Photoshop CC (2014.2.2 release). After switching a few times between programs back to Photoshop I get the following artefacts. Only remedy seems to be restarting Photoshop. Even stranger, saving the current file in a JPG will even save the artefacts to the file.

[image]

Couldn't find any related problems by good ol' fashioned Googling. Could this be a Photoshop bug or maybe even a damaged CPU?

**Edit**: Here is a animation showing how this affects in practice.

[image]

Comment: Are you using OpenGL? More likely to be an issue if your other apps use it too. Looks like a backbuffer issue.

Comment: @Tetsujin would the buffer have any impact on how it saves?

Comment: not certain, tbh. Would be easy enough to switch off OGL support in pshop & see if it stops happening. Prefs/performance to en/disable it 'Use Graphics processor' or tweak the amount of RAM OGL can use in prefs/3D [it will use OpenGL for more than just 3D, but they're the only 2 real tweak points.]

Comment: I seem to have OpenGL enabled. "AMD Radeon HD 6970M OpenGL Engine" I'm now disabling it, I'll get back asap with results. BTW, I'm also using Adobe Flash CC simultaneously, might that cause any problems?

Comment: Sorry, I really only use photoshop, but I've experienced issues on various machines with using OGL on 2 simultaneous apps - though also by not assigning it a good memory usage in the first place, allowing for other apps & total system/GPU RAM - so that's next to play with if still no joy

Comment: It already has been working flawlessly for longer then I can remember, so I think my problem is with the OGL. Is there any way to fix this without disabling OGL?

Comment: You could try tweaking in the advanced settings, under the OGL switch prefs/performance; though idk specifics. If I find a machine struggles I just mess with those & the overall RAM requirements til it behaves again. Presumably depends on total RAM, GPU RAM & also RAM requirements for any other running apps

Comment: Okay, thanks anyways! I'll try tweaking with the settings in the near future, deadlines atm are preventing me of doing so. ;)

Comment: Determine whether it is an image problem or just a display problem.  Print the image and see if the output has the problem.

Comment: @fixer1234 When CMD + P in Photoshop and printing when I actually see the artifacts, it prints exactly the same as what I see on screen.

Comment: Can you post "before" and "after" images (a before image of the current one if you still have it).  That way people will be sure of exactly what the artifacts are.  Also, what is the file format (all jpg or is there any conversion going on)?  What are the other programs?

Comment: @fixer1234 I just added a animated gif to my original post, this shows how Photoshop reacts to a new white image and coloring in it with the brush. Also showing contents of Save for web

Comment: @Tetsujin I seem to have the same problems now, even with OGL disabled.

Comment: Looking at your gif, I've never seen anything like that before, sorry. It doesn't look quite like the issues I have had to work round previously. Not sure what else to suggest.

Comment: Reinstalled Photoshop today, before uninstalling I checked the option to remove all preferences. Reinstalled, and still seeing the same problems...

Answer (score 0):

Turn off hardware acceleration inside Photoshop preferences.

The issue, like everyone said, is a fault in openGL. Turning hardware acceleration off should help.

Comment: OpenGL is involved only in rendering the image on the screen.  The problem here involves the image being corrupted.  The OP also commented that the problem occurred after disabling OGL.